# how lowmemorykiller kills an active background service

Tags: android, android-service, android-automotive

An Android app part of core applications installed under /system/priv-app/.  This app must show UI on top of all screens when vehicle mode is changed to Reverse. So I defined a sticky service which will be running in background to listen events and show UI on screen (used SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW).

While doing sanity testing, and UI is showing, `lowmemorykiller` killed my service and UI is gone, which is not expected behavior.

As per guidelines, I must not use `persistent=true` in manifest.

I wonder, why lowmemorykiller has killed my service which is active on screen?

If that was an expected behavior, then is there a way that I can define a sticky service as a foreground which will start on boot and do not show a notification?

Comment: No.  On old Android versions sure.  On modern Android versions they've tried to prevent everything you're trying to do.  If you want a persistent service, you must show a notification.

Comment: Yes, but this is priva-app, so I though there would be any extra privileges.